# ServiceStack - endpoints don't show up on metadata page?

Tags: servicestack, dto

ServiceStack - endpoints don't show up on metadata page?

Comment: Is TransactionDetails implemented in a Service? If so please show the method signature and double check its Service class inherits Service.

Comment: Your impl looks fine. Does your AppHost constructor reference the Services Assembly where `CreditTransactionService` is defined?

Comment: Damn, i changed it to public AppHost()
            : base("Maison", typeof(CreditTransactionService).Assembly)
        {

        } and now there are on metadata page. CreditTransactionService is just one of my many services, why put it there and all the rest will show up? Thanks.

Comment: When you reference `typeof(CreditTransactionService).Assembly` your referencing the entire **Assembly** where `CreditTransactionService` is defined, i.e. not just a single type. The AppHost requires you specify assemblies where your Service implementations are defined, I've added an answer with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure your `AppHost` references the **Assembly** your Services are defined by specifying them in the base constructor, e.g:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    AppHost() : base("Maison", typeof(CreditTransactionService).Assembly) {} 
}
```

Comment: Awww. Got it. Thanks a lot.